# Does your home country get notified when you enter another country

Tags: customs-and-immigration

When you enter a new country do they report your entry to your home country?
Do countries track where their citizens are?

Comment: This is broader than a continent!

Answer (score 6):

There are currently 7376850  different combinations of citizen from "country A" travels from "country B" to "country C" so it's almost impossible to give a comprehensive answer.

However, in most cases the answer is "no". If you are a US citizen, crossing the border from, say, Denmark into Sweden, neither Danish or Swedish authority would report anything to the US authorities.

Countries typically keep track when you arrive and when you leave, but exchange of data between different countries is fairly rare.

Comment: _neither Danish or Swedish authority_ - neither of them would even know you crossed the border.

Comment: The train from Copenhagen airport to Malmo always makes a stop at the border to allow for passport control, so it's technically possible that they may actually check